# Class is not defined Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to include 'Flop' Class into html file, there is app.js content:

```
class Flop {

    size;
    difficulty;

    constructor() {
        console.log("Created");
    }

    start() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("flop");
        var content = canvas.getContent("2d");
    }

    setup() {

    }
}
```

And there is index.html file:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Flop</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="flop"></canvas>

    <script src="main/app.js"></script>

    <script>
        var flop = new Flop();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and what I got in a console that Flop is not defined, the question is what to do if I actually want to use this class and how should I include it

Comment: Since you are using class, are you using any bundlers like webpack or grunt?

Comment: You should also get a syntax error in your console! `size; difficulty;` is not valid in a `class` body.

Comment: you can try to add the <script src="main/app.js"></script> to your header. In that case the included file will be loaded before the body is visible

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst Scripts are executed in order.

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst Even if that was the case, if you use webpack or any tool, they wrap your class in an IIFE to maintain scope and prevent bleeding to global scope. So `Flop` will not be available on global scope

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't right. The issue is with the size; and difficulty; Iy you remove those lines, the code will work.

Comment: Okay, got it, needed to delete those lines, thanks guys

Comment: @miloszowi since your script says `app.js` I assumed you might. Still there are few useful comments that will help you.